# How to stop a report prompting for fields not supplied in query?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a report for multiple uses, but sometimes the query doesn't includes all the fields in the report. When this happens the report asks in a popup window for the missing field value. I would like to hide those windows and set "" or nothing by default.

How might I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend restructuring the report to account for multiple Record Sources rather than suppressing the errors you're currently seeing. There are a few ways to do this.

It's hard to provide too many specifics without knowing more about your report, but you could consider the following:

1) Use an unbound report and dynamically populate fields as needed based on your query's recordset. You can vary which fields are populated based on which query you are using as a data source, and the other fields will be left blank and/or can be hidden.
However, this may cause issues if you need to distribute this database to other users or complile the database into an executable version.

2) Create a VBA routine which dynamically creates or modifies report objects. In this case, you would dynamically create new report objects (and the controls within them) based on multiple report profiles (no need to re-create existing reports). You could specify control positions, definitions, etc. and only vary as needed. Depending on your report, this may be fairly easy to do by creating the report from scratch using all fields, and then simply remove the steps required for fields you're not using in a given report.

3) Continue using a report bound to one query, but modify the query definition as needed to remove field values as needed by dynamically building SQL strings within VBA. So the query would always contain all report fields, but in some cases return the real data, and in others would return dummy results i.e. "". You can also change what fields have GROUP BY or WHERE clauses.

I hope that helps - good luck!

Comment: The report it's not so linear, it has 2 rows per table line, they are positioned in a special way to keep size to the minimum. I cannot generate automatically in vba the object because of 2 reasons: the objects must be in the visual, because I don't want to maintain them by setting the x and y manually and refresh to see if it's in the right position. 2th because I don't even know which fields are shown, I should parse the query, which is very difficult. The last thing I would do if I cannot suppress the pop-ups it's to make the dummy thing. But that's difficult because the interface has like

Comment: 20 different options to select from, I would need to check for which combination I should add a dummy field and for which I should not.. The easier and more practical way it's to suppress the notifications.

Comment: If you generate the querydef SQL dynamically, you can simply say, if needed show field, else show "" for each of the 20 options. Are there like "groups" of similar reports that are similar to each other?

Comment: I don't know how to do what you say... I only have a report that it's used for all those queries to show..